# Minimal distance from a point to other 2 points in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra

There exist three points in a 3d space, $A=(x,y,0), B=(a,0,2), C=(-a,0,2)$ where $a>0$.

My question is, how to find the minimal distance from point $A$ to point $B$ and point $C$?

Comment: Draw a picture and see

Comment: Minimum of AB+AC or AB+BC

Comment: AB+AC, I tried to simplify a hard calculus problem to this (but I think I failed), look for the real question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804455/the-maximum-light-intensity-coming-from-2-light-bulbs-on-the-xy-plane

Comment: The minimum distance is achieved with A = (0, 0, 0) isn't it?

Comment: Hint: use the symmetry of the arrangement. This is equivalent to asking for the minimum-perimeter triangle for a given fixed area.