# The maximum light intensity coming from two light bulbs on the $xy$-plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

There is two light bulbs, one on $(-a,0,2)$ and the other on $(a,0,2)$, where $a>0$.

The light intensity coming from two light bulbs on the $x$-axis and $y$-axis (where $z=0$) can be calculated using the following equation:
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{(x+a)^2+y^2+2^2} + \frac{1}{(x-a)^2+y^2+2^2}.$$
My question is, how to find the maximum point(s) (or critical points) of $f$.

*Notes: There can be one or two critical points, depending on $a$.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$For any critical point $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$,$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0) = 0.
$$
Because for any $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$,\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) &= -2 \left( \frac{x + a}{((x + a)^2 + y^2 + 2^2)^2} + \frac{x - a}{((x - a)^2 + y^2 + 2^2)^2} \right),\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) &= -2 \left( \frac{y}{((x + a)^2 + y^2 + 2^2)^2} + \frac{y}{((x - a)^2 + y^2 + 2^2)^2} \right),
\end{align*}
then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0) = 0 \Rightarrow y_0 = 0$, and\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{\Longrightarrow}}{} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, 0) = 0\\
&\Longrightarrow \frac{x_0 + a}{((x_0 + a)^2 + 2^2)^2} + \frac{x_0 - a}{((x_0 - a)^2 + 2^2)^2} = 0\\
&\Longrightarrow (x_0 + a)((x_0 - a)^2 + 2^2)^2 + (x_0 - a)((x_0 + a)^2 + 2^2)^2 = 0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Also, for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying (1), $(x_0, 0)$ is indeed a critical point. Since for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$,\begin{align*}
(x + a)((x - a)^2 + 2^2)^2 &= (x + a)(x - a)^4 + 8(x + a)(x - a)^2 + 16(x + a)\\
&= (x^2 - a^2)(x - a)^3 + 8(x^2 - a^2)(x - a) + 16(x + a),
\end{align*}
then\begin{align*}
&\peq (x + a)((x - a)^2 + 2^2)^2 + (x - a)((x + a)^2 + 2^2)^2\\
&= (x^2 - a^2)(x - a)^3 + 8(x^2 - a^2)(x - a) + 16(x + a)\\
&\peq + (x^2 - a^2)(x + a)^3 + 8(x^2 - a^2)(x + a) + 16(x - a)\\
&= (x^2 - a^2) \Bigl((x - a)^3 + (x + a)^3 + 8(x - a) + 8(x + a)\Bigr) + 32x\\
&= (x^2 - a^2)(2x^3 + 6a^2 x + 16x) + 32x = 2x \Bigl( (x^2 - a^2)(x^2 + 3a^2 + 8) + 16 \Bigr)\\
&= 2x \Bigl(x^4 + (2a^2 + 8)x^2 - (3a^4 + 8a^2 - 16) \Bigr) = 2x \Bigl( (x^2 + a^2 + 4)^2 - 4a^2 (a^2 + 4) \Bigr).
\end{align*}
Note that$$
(a^2 + 4)^2 - 4a^2 (a^2 + 4) = -(3a^4 + 8a^2 - 16) = -(a^2 + 4)(3a^2 - 4).
$$
If $(a^2 + 4)^2 - 4a^2 (a^2 + 4) \geqslant 0$, i.e. $0 < a \leqslant \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, then $(1) \Leftrightarrow x_0 = 0$. If $(a^2 + 4)^2 - 4a^2 (a^2 + 4) < 0$, i.e. $a > \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, then$$
(1) \Longleftrightarrow x_0 = 0 \text{ or } \pm \sqrt{a^2 + 4} \sqrt{2a - \sqrt{a^2 + 4}}.
$$
Therefore, if $0 < a \leqslant \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, then the only critical point is $(0, 0)$. If $a > \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, then the critical points are $(0, 0)$ and $(\pm \sqrt{a^2 + 4} \sqrt{2a - \sqrt{a^2 + 4}}, 0)$.

Comment: Your answer is 100% correct, but do you think you can solve it without partial derivatives? I mean can you figure out the answer using linear algebra?

Comment: The partial derivatives is deliberately being picked hard to force us to using some linear algebra, I think one way is to use the distance of a point to a line formula, but still coudn't solve the question.

Comment: @BsharaZahran I don’t see how linear algebra would enter into this in any useful way. It’s fairly clear from the symmetry of the function that critical points lie on the $x$-axis, so you can reduce it to a one-dimensional problem, but you’re still dealing with the sum of two inverse-square functions.

Comment: @amd Yes, I did reduce f(x,y) to say h(x), but I still get the same difficulty with the derivative part, The answer above is great but I think it's a bit too advanced for a Calculus II class. The original question in my assignment hinted to solve this part algebraically, meaning, not using partial derivatives.

Comment: To be more specific, I kept getting stuck after deriving the function, the difficult part is the factorization that Alex Francisco did around the "Note that".

Comment: @BsharaZahran That doesn’t sound like it has anything to do with *linear* algebra, though.

Comment: @BsharaZahran Well, everything after (1) such as the “note that” part is pure algebra no more difficult than solving (intrinsically) quadratic equations. And is that the only hint given in the assignment?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Oh, now I see how you used the quadratic formula, all clear now, thanks for the help! and yes this is the only hint.

Comment: @amd Looks like I misunderstood the hint.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco At the very last row is it a typo that y and x swapped? "(0, something) instead of (something, 0)"

Comment: @BsharaZahran Yes. Thank you for pointing out :)